# groupadd command not found in Cygwin

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, cygwin

I have Windows 7 64-bit PC. I have installed Cygwin version 2.6.0 on it in c:\cygwin64 directory.

There was no **/etc/passwd** file. So I create that file by using `mkpasswd -l > /etc/passwd` command.

There was no **/etc/group** file. So I created that file by using `mkgroup -l > /etc/group` command.

Now I want to add a group using `groupadd` command. So I type in `groupadd -g 535 finance_2` command. But I get this error message:

> -bash: groupadd: command not found

Is this command part of any package of Cygwin which I dont have so have to download?

Or this command is totally missing from Cygwin? In that case how to add a group in Cygwin?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your users in Windows, then use them in cygwin :

> The mkpasswd program can be used to create a /etc/passwd file. Cygwin doesn't need this file, because it reads user information from the Windows account databases

[mkpassword on cygwin.com](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/mkpasswd.html)

Answer (score 2):

#### -bash: groupadd: command not found

Cygwin does not have a `groupadd`` command.

**Workaround:**

> Hi:
>
> Can anybody tell me which packages do I need to install in order to
>   execute the following commands:
>
> groupadd
>   useradd

...

> To do this on cygwin, you need to add the user accounts and groups
>   in windows, then regenerate your passwd and group files using
>   mkpasswd/mkgroup.
>
> If you want to add windows user groups/accounts from the cygwin
>   environment, you can invoke the 'doze commands "net user" and "net
>   localgroup" from a shell/script/whatever.  Run "net user /?" and "net
>   localgroup /?" for syntax details.

Source [packages for groupadd and useradd commands](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2006-04/msg00512.html)